# Add a custom row in Woocommerce admin edit order pages before "Order total"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I am searching for the correct hook to insert a new row with custom data here, but I didn't come across any correct answer.

Please check the image for the position:
[image: Please check the image for the position]

Please any help will be appreciated.

Comment: and what you want to show exactly with new row?

Comment: @R.K.Bhardwaj since I made a discount on the shipping fee when the sub total is over 200, I want to indicate this at the here as well. I've already added into the front-end and the email and this is how it looks like: [link](http://gravitystudio.io/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Screen-Shot-2017-12-20-at-3.22.13-PM.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a custom function hooked in `woocommerce_admin_order_totals_after_tax` action hook, you will be able to display a custom row just before the "Order total" row:

```
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_totals_after_tax', 'custom_admin_order_totals_after_tax', 10, 1 );
function custom_admin_order_totals_after_tax( $order_id ) {

    // Here set your data and calculations
    $label = __( 'Custom label', 'woocommerce' );
    $value = 'Value';

    // Output
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="label"><?php echo $label; ?>:</td>
            <td width="1%"></td>
            <td class="custom-total"><?php echo $value; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
}
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works… You will get something like:

[image]

OR …

For a single string text use this instead:

```
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_totals_after_tax', 'custom_admin_order_totals_after_tax', 10, 1 );
function custom_admin_order_totals_after_tax( $order_id ) {

    // Here set your text
    $text = __( 'This is your custom text', 'woocommerce' );

    // Output
    echo '<tr><td class="label" colspan="3">' . echo $label . '</td></tr>';
}
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works… You will get something like:

[image]

Comment: Man!! really thanks for such a detail answer! Let me verify and i will give you a big thumbs up! By the way can I ask a stupid question? Since I couldn't find all these hooks from the woocomnmerce official docs, are they hiding this? or I should look for all these information from somewhere else reliable? Thanks:)

Comment: Verified, Thanks mate!

Comment: @WeijianZhao You should look in the sourde code of the WC plugin in includes/admin…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec: is there any hook in admin to change the order total? I have added a different payment method with Credits and not actual money, So need to change the order total. I searched a lot but did not found.